# smoothscroll is not working when targetting name attribute in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Smooth scroll is not working when i'm targeting name attribute using smoothscroll plugin but smoothscroll is working fine if i'm targetting id attribute. Getting the below console erros, please suggest how to resolve.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var class1 = $("[class^='test']");
    $('class1').on('click', function (event) {
        var scrollStatus = $(this).attr('data-smooth-scroll');
        if(scrollStatus !== 'false' && scrollStatus !== undefined) {
            var actualHrefValue = $(this).attr("href");
            var actualNameValue = $('[name="' + actualHrefValue.substr(1) + '"]');
            if(actualHrefValue.charAt(0) === "#") {
                if(actualHrefValue !== '#' && actualHrefValue !== null) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    document.querySelector(actualNameValue).scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth', block: "start" });
                }
            }
        }
    });

});
```

**Error:**
[image]

**HTML:**

```
<a type="hyperlink" class="test_1" href="#link">Click</a>

<a name="link"></a>
```

Comment: I believe you forgot to post the console errors. All I see is the code example.

Comment: @Martin, Added console error

Comment: Can you add the elements that you are targeting as well? Just to get a more overall idea.

Comment: try console logging the values you intend to use, I suspect you could be just making an error there and actually referencing nothing (null)

Comment: @Snsa90, the problem is `selector: "[name="#link"]"` is not working in query.selector

Answer (score 1):

You are using

```
document.querySelector(actualNameValue)
```

where the actualNameValue is already an element

```
var actualNameValue = $('[name="' + actualHrefValue.substr(1) + '"]');
```

Try

```
actualNameValue.scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth', block: "start" });
```

instead of

```
document.querySelector(actualNameValue).scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth', block: "start" });
```